# css padding before and after datalist?

Tags: html, css

I have a datalist on my website that displays as a box of links (depending on the page, between 1 and 30 links).

I need to get a bit of padding before and after the list to make it look a bit better, but I don't want to have that padding added between every single list item.

I have tried the :before and :after selectors in my CSS but it doesn't seem to do anything.

**HTML**

```
<div>
        <asp:DataList ID="dlSubCategories" class="SubCatLinks" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="3" runat="server"  ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" 
        Width="100%" SelectedItemStyle-BackColor="#F4F4F4" SelectedItemStyle-Font-Bold="true" >
            <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Hyperlink ID="hlSubCategory" runat="server" CssClass="dlItem"></asp:Hyperlink>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <SelectedItemTemplate>
                <asp:Hyperlink ID="hlSubCategory" runat="server" CssClass="dlItem"></asp:Hyperlink>
            </SelectedItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.dlItem                         { float:left; text-align:left; padding-left:10px; background-color:#F4F4F4;}
.SubCatLinks                    { float:left; width:740px; background-color: #F4F4F4; border-radius:2px; padding-bottom:20px; margin-bottom:20px; padding-left:5px; margin-top:15px; }
.SubCatLinks :before            { padding-top:20px; }
```

**Example of Page**

I'm after some extra gray space before the top row of links and below the bottom row but not in between the rows.

[image]

Comment: try add `margin: 10px 0 10px 0;`, to your div

Comment: Thanks, but I think I need to use the padding option instead (I want to increase the background colored space around my links, not add whitespace). Which CSS class should I add it to?

Comment: so, i don't see any links in HTML. Could you create an example of your output?

Comment: Why can't you add `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` to the actual DataList? Either that, or add `padding-top` to `.dlItem:first-of-type` and `padding-bottom` to `.dlItem:last-of-type`

Comment: @AleshaOleg I have added an image of the standard layout of the page.

Comment: @ChrisHinton and where you links? They starts from Amplifies Audio, Car Hi-FI, etc.?

Comment: Yeah, everything in the gray box. It's databound depending on the page. @Jakemmarsh, thanks for your suggestion but it didn't work on .dlItem and it added space to every line when I tried it with .SubCatLinks.

Answer (score 0):

adjust the `line-height` see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/ru6yvrce/196/

`.lineheight{line-height: 40px;}`